# how can I put pictures in the center | HTML, CSS

Tags: html

```
 <span style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/cat/comments/lzr58y/funny_boy/">
            <img src="https://i.redd.it/3vjzzg8e3ml61.jpg" alt="https://www.reddit.com/r/cat/comments/lzr58y/funny_boy/" width="640" height="910">
        </a>
    </span>
    <!--how can I center pictures ? -->
```

This is the code I made it and I want to make this picture to go in the center. I tried to do it with `text-align: center;` and it won't go to center. well, I know `text-align` is for "text", so is their anything for pictures?

Comment: i dont want all of my images to be in center i just need this in the center

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Of which is to use margins and manually position it
2. Manually do it with position: relative or position: absolute
3. You can use `auto` as in `margin: auto` to achieve centering without manually doing it.

There are other options, but these are some that might help

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Try changing the span element with div element and remove the sizes in your img element (width,height) and control it from your css + add the css to your code

Comment: It's absolutely incorrect. First, you should not change all the `<div>`'s width (you should use a CSS class instead); second, **never** set both width and height of an image in CSS (which in this case results in aspect ratio distortion; try `height: auto` instead).

Comment: @Raptor This css is just to explain how to use margin: 0 auto; to center elements, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The `text-align:center` actually works on images. but the element must have the `display:block` property to get elements to it's center.

`<span>` element doesn't have the `display:block`, so you can just add it.

Here's a working example:

```html
<span style="text-align: center;display:block">
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/cat/comments/lzr58y/funny_boy/">
            <img src="https://i.redd.it/3vjzzg8e3ml61.jpg" alt="https://www.reddit.com/r/cat/comments/lzr58y/funny_boy/" width="340" >
        </a>
    </span>
```

You can also use `<div>` instead of `<span>` which have the `display:block;` property by default

Comment: The explanation of the answer could be elaborated a bit. `<span>` is an inline element, in which dimension is depended on the content. `<div>` is a block element, which by default has the property of `display: block`, spanning its dimension across the whole width.

Answer (score 0):

```
span{
  display:grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

Use this to put anything both horizontally and vertically center

Answer (score 0):

```html
<span style="text-align: center;position: absolute;">
      <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/cat/comments/lzr58y/funny_boy/">
        <img src="https://i.redd.it/3vjzzg8e3ml61.jpg" alt="https://www.reddit.com/r/cat/comments/lzr58y/funny_boy/" width="640" height="910" style="
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
">
      </a>
    </span>
```

You can give position and based on position set left:50%